# Dagger 2 Set Multibinding doesn't work for SimpleEntry in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, multibinding

The below multibinding works, when provide a `Pair` as `IntoSet`

```
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryOne(): Pair<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 1"
        return Pair(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryTwo(): Pair<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 2"
        return Pair(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    fun randomKeyValueMap(entries: Set<Pair<String, String>>): Map<String, String> {
        val randomKeyValueMap = LinkedHashMap<String, String>(entries.size)
        for (entry in entries) {
            randomKeyValueMap[entry.first] = entry.second
        }
        return randomKeyValueMap
    }
```

However when turn `Pair` into `SimpleEntry`, it doesn't work anymore.

```
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryOne(): AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 1"
        return AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryTwo(): AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 2"
        return AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    fun randomKeyValueMap(entries: Set<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>>): Map<String, String> {
        val randomKeyValueMap = LinkedHashMap<String, String>(entries.size)
        for (entry in entries) {
            randomKeyValueMap[entry.key] = entry.value
        }
        return randomKeyValueMap
    }
```

It complaints

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Set<? extends java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface MyComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Set<? extends java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>> is injected at
```

Note, if I use the `Entry` for Java, it works fine. Only doesn't work for Kotlin.

Comment: Submitted a dagger 2 issue in https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1650

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I need @JvmSuppressWildcards

```
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryOne(): Map.Entry<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 1"
        return AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun entryTwo(): Map.Entry<String, String> {
        val key = randomStringGenerator()
        val value = "Random Value 2"
        return AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, value)
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    fun randomKeyValueMap(entries: Set<Map.Entry<String, String>>): Map<String, String> {
        val randomKeyValueMap = LinkedHashMap<String, String>(entries.size)
        for (entry in entries) {
            randomKeyValueMap[entry.key] = entry.value
        }
        return randomKeyValueMap
    }
```